# How to handle multiple database type support with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, mariadb

I need to support Migration for MariaDb and SqlServer in a project.
Currently, I edited migration files which created by add-migration command. You can see some part of migration file.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Tbl1",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")
                    .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 100, nullable: true),
                Measurement = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 100, nullable: true),
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Tbl1", x => x.Id);
            });
```

With that change, my migration files can support both database types (MariaDb and SqlServer).
But, I have to set and use the same ColumnType for both.
I would like to know is there any best practice provided by Entityframework to support multiple database types or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Migrations with Multiple Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) which discusses exactly that scenario with the following two approaches:

> #### Two migration sets
>
> In the first approach, you generate two migrations for each model change.
>
> One way to do this is to put each migration set in a separate assembly and manually switch the active provider (and migrations assembly) between adding the two migrations.
>
> Another approach that makes working with the tools easier is to create a new type that derives from your DbContext and overrides the active provider. This type is used at design time when adding or applying migrations.

```cs
class MySqliteDbContext : MyDbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=my.db");
}
```

> Note
>
> Since each migration set uses its own DbContext types, this approach doesn't
> require using a separate migrations assembly.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context MyDbContext --output-dir Migrations/SqlServerMigrations
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context MySqliteDbContext --output-dir Migrations/SqliteMigrations
```

> #### One migration set
>
> If you don't like having two sets of migrations, you can manually combine them into a single set that can be applied to both providers.
>
> Annotations can coexist since a provider ignores any annotations that it doesn't understand. For example, a primary key column that works with both Microsoft SQL Server and SQLite might look like this.

```cs
Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy",
        SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
```

> If operations can be applied only for one provider, or they're different between providers, use the ActiveProvider property to determine which provider is active:

```cs
if (migrationBuilder.ActiveProvider == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        name: "EntityFrameworkHiLoSequence");
}
```

---

#### Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql specific

Also see [Implement alternatives to the current behavior to always throw, if a schema has been set for an object #982](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/982) and references about how to handle the case, that MySQL und MariaDB don't know what a SQL Server Schema (e.g. `dbo`) is (assuming you are using
[Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) as the provider to access the MariaDB database).

Here are some code options:

```cs
// Throw an exception, if a schema is being used. This is the default.
options.UseMySql(myConnectionString, b => b.SchemaBehavior(MySqlSchemaBehavior.Throw))

// Silently ignore any schema definitions.
options.UseMySql(myConnectionString, b => b.SchemaBehavior(MySqlSchemaBehavior.Ignore))

// Use the specified translator delegate to translate from an input schema and object name to
// an output object name whenever a schema is being used.
options.UseMySql(myConnectionString, b => b.SchemaBehavior(MySqlSchemaBehavior.Translate,
    (schema, entity) => $"{schema ?? "dbo"}_{entity}"))
```