# How to get active provider in EF6 DbMigration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am struggling with generating conditional code enabling a single migration to target multiple providers - in our project we use EF6 with MSSQL and PostgreSQL.
Is there a way to determine the active provider on adding new migration level?
Something like this:

```
public partial class TestMigration: DbMigration
{
    protected override void Up()
    {
        if(ActiveProvider == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
        {
            // do something SQL Server - specific
        }
        if(ActiveProvider == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL")
        {
            // do something PostgreSQL- specific
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124490/how-to-handle-multiple-database-type-support-with-entity-framework) is a great example of how to do it using EF Core but is there any equivalent in EF6?